# 3 open source libraries to plot graphs both in browser and printed

Tags: open-source, javascript, web-development, php, graphs

I'm searching for essentially 3 graph open-source libraries that could help me write personal software.

1. An interactive JS graph library, I need to draw interactive graphs that could go fullscreen and be updated and refreshed dynamically. If I can handle and modify elements with jsQuery and CSS selectors, it would be better. If it uses canvas elements and achieves high refresh, even better. Must be responsive and zoomable in case, would like to handle very big cloud graphs.
2. A static PHP graph image-generating library, but maybe for that one jpGraph could work.
3. A graph library that is able to port to vector, svg or pdf one of the above solution to big printed map pdf.

Maybe do exists libraries or frameworks that are able to do it all together or maybe I have to use multiple PHP and js libraries, it's not a problem.

My goal is to be able to display complex graphs UI and extended zoomable conceptual map data (the ones you do with xmind just for reference) in the reunions with friends on a big tv (browser in fullscreen), as well being able to produce high res or vector images to be able to print them and give them as printed material for study.

Answer (score 1):

[Chart js](https://www.chartjs.org/) or [d3](https://d3js.org/) or [Canvas](https://canvasjs.com/).
It depends if you are building your website with certain framework like angular or react they integrate well with some libraries more than others. But data rich graphs and analytics may lead you to python libraries like matplotlib or seaborn.

More experienced developers may tell you how to integrate these libraries through web via python frameworks. For me, I can do both data analytics and web development separately.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not a real open source option but I've found [amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/) very nice, the 4.x is based on SVG, the 5.x is based on CANVAS however the nice thing is that the syntax is mainly the same among the 2 versions.